# Redefining connected Shimura datum

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, shimura-varieties

Firstly, let us fix a semisimple reductive linear algebriac group $G$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I am interested in seeing if I can bring the definition of connected Shimura datum (which is defined using some properties on a $G^{\operatorname{ad}}({\mathbb{R}})^+$-conjugacy class of homomorphisms $U_1\rightarrow G^{\operatorname{ad}}_{\mathbb{R}}$) closer to the definition of Shimura datum (which is defined using some properties on a $G({\mathbb{R}})$-conjugacy class of homomorphisms $\mathbb{S}\rightarrow G_{\mathbb{R}}$).

The theorem that gives me hope that this is possible is the following result in [Milne]:

> Proposition 4.9: Let $(G,D)$ be a connected Shimura datum, and let $X$ be the $G^{\operatorname{ad}}(\mathbb{R})$-conjugacy class of homomorphisms $\mathbb{S}\rightarrow G_{\mathbb{R}}$ containing $D$. Then, $D$ is a connected component of $X$, and the stablizer of $D$ in $G^{\operatorname{ad}}(\mathbb{R})$ is $G^{\operatorname{ad}}(\mathbb{R})^+$.

My first question is probably a silly one. Milne is clearly identifying homomorphisms in $D$ which are of the form $U_1\rightarrow G^{\operatorname{ad}}_{\mathbb{R}}$ with homomorphisms $\mathbb{S}\rightarrow G_{\mathbb{R}}$. While we can compose the former with $\mathbb{S}\rightarrow U_1$ which maps $z\mapsto z/\bar{z}$, I don't see why the resultant homomorphism $\mathbb{S}\rightarrow G^{\operatorname{ad}}_{\mathbb{R}}$ should pass through $G_\mathbb{R}$.

The second question is what I have been wondering most about. Can we redefine a connected Shimura datum as being a pair $(G,D)$ consisting of a semisimple algebraic group $G$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and a $G^{\operatorname{ad}}(\mathbb{R})^+$- conjugacy class of homomorphisms $h:\mathbb{S}\rightarrow G_\mathbb{R}$
satisfying the following conditions:

SV1: for all $h\in D$, only the characters $z/\bar{z}, 1, \bar{z}/z$ occur in the representation of $\mathbb{S}$ on $\operatorname{Lie}(G)_\mathbb{C}$ defined by $\operatorname{Ad}\circ h$.

SV2: for all $h\in D$, $\operatorname{ad}(h(i))$ is a Cartan involution on $G^{\operatorname{ad}}_\mathbb{R}$

SV3: $G^{\operatorname{ad}}$ has no $\mathbb{Q}$-factor on which the projection of $h$ is trivial.

Remark: Definition 4.22 in [Milne] states a similar (but not exactly the same) definition.

References:

*Milne, J. S.*, Introduction to Shimura varieties, Arthur, James (ed.) et al., Harmonic analysis, the trace formula, and Shimura varieties. Proceedings of the Clay Mathematics Institute 2003 summer school, Toronto, Canada, June 2–27, 2003. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 0-8218-3844-X/pbk). Clay Mathematics Proceedings 4, 265-378 (2005). [ZBL1148.14011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1148.14011).